# UIWebView and Bootstrap css tables

Tags: objective-c, twitter-bootstrap-3, mustache

I am creating an application that will show to the user a formatted message in an UIWebView loading local HTML content.

I am using GRMustache to render the html to be displayed and bootstrap as css.

Everything works fine, the css is loaded, but when i want to display tables, the css is not recognized.

I don't know if UIWebView is not capable to recognize the css of the tables, but in the apple documentation just read that have the same capabilities than safari.

Here i put my template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        {{style}}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<h1> Message </h1>

<button class="btn btn-success"> Button </button>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
            {{# detalle}}
            <tr >
                <td>  {{capitalized(key) }} </td>
                <td> {{ capitalized(object)}}  </td>
            </tr>
            {{/ detalle}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Here is an image of my UIWebView:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/or5vrqxxqbjqjoh/bootstrap%20app.png

The button css is rendered fine, but the table is not striped.
I checked my css, thinking than that was the problem, but it was just fine.
In this moment I can't find an answer for this problem.

Comment: can you add jsfiddle.